# API for updating a confluence page with table from a sql server for c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, confluence

I am able to login to the confluence page. I want to update the page with details from a table in sql server i.e., I want the table present in my sql server to appear on the confluence page. Please help! I have tried several things but in vain. This is my code. Thanks!

try
            {
                ConfluenceSoapServiceService oWikiUpdateService = new ConfluenceSoapServiceService();

```
            String sLoginToken = String.Empty;

            try
            {
                sLoginToken = oWikiUpdateService.login(confluenceLogin, confluencePassword);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Login attempt failed");
            }

            RemotePage oPage = oWikiUpdateService.getPage(sLoginToken, pageID);

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        csb.DataSource = server;
        csb.InitialCatalog = database;
        csb.IntegratedSecurity = true;

        string connString = csb.ToString();


        string queryString = "select * from XMLCatalogServer";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = queryString;

            connection.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //Send these to your WinForms textboxes
                    string SSAS_server = reader["Server"].ToString();

                    string cpu = reader["CPU#"].ToString();

                    string memory = reader["RAMSizeInGb"].ToString();

                    string totalSpace = reader["TotalDiskSpaceInGb"].ToString();
                    string ver = reader["SSASVersion#"].ToString();
                    string edition = reader["SSASEdition"].ToString();
                    string env = reader["Environment"].ToString();
                    string app = reader["Application"].ToString();

                }
            }
        }


            oWikiUpdateService.logout(sLoginToken);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: html include macro allows the inclusion of an external html file in a Confluence page https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Enabling+the+html-include+Macro

Comment: I want it in c#. I found a way to upload but the formatting goes away. It just updates one after another even if there is a significant amount of space after each word.